# Android Share Multiple Images with Other Apps

Tags: java, android, android-glide, android-fileprovider

I'm attempting to use the native Android share functionality to share a set of images I retrieved using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). So any app that is compatible with the images will show up in Android's share menu.

I created a method that gets invoked when share is clicked.

```
private void onShareClicked() { 
    GlideUrl glideUrl = new GlideUrl(url1, new LazyHeaders.Builder().addHeader("x-auth-token", mToken).build());
    FutureTarget<File> image1 = mGlide.load(glideUrl).downloadOnly(SIZE_ORIGINAL, SIZE_ORIGINAL);

    glideUrl = new GlideUrl(url2, new LazyHeaders.Builder().addHeader("x-auth-token", token).build());
    FutureTarget<File> image2 = mGlide.load(glideUrl).downloadOnly(SIZE_ORIGINAL, SIZE_ORIGINAL);

    new ShareImagesTask(this, "image/png").execute(image1, image2);
}
```

Then created `ShareImagesTask` which allows you to share multiple images by completing the request to get the images files via Glide:

```
public class ShareImagesTask extends AsyncTask<FutureTarget<File>, Void, ArrayList<Uri>> {

    private final Context mContext;
    private final String mMimeType;

    public ShareImagesTask(Context context, String mimeType) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mMimeType = mimeType;
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Uri> doInBackground(FutureTarget<File>... targets) {
        final ArrayList<Uri> imageUris = new ArrayList<>(targets.length);

        for(FutureTarget<File> target : targets) {
            try {
                File file = target.get();
                Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, "com.myapp.fileprovider", file);
                imageUris.add(uri);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.w("SHARE", "Sharing failed for one or more image files.", ex);
            }
        }

        return imageUris;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Uri> result) {
        if(!result.isEmpty()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, result);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.setType(mMimeType);
            mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Your Photo"));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my **AndroidManifest.xml** `FileProvider`:

```
<provider
    android:name=".provider.MyAppFileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.myapp.fileprovider"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true"
    android:exported="false">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
</provider>
```

And finally, `filepaths.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <cache-path name="shared_images" path="/data/data/com.myapp/cache/image_manager_disk_cache/"/>
</paths>
```

I am able to get to the point of calling `FileProvider.getUriForProvider()` and it gives the exception below. I have also tried changing the path in `filepaths.xml` to variations of the path mentioned in the exception but I get the same error. Any ideas?

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root
>   that contains
>   /data/data/com.myapp/cache/image_manager_disk_cache/11fa9845150748cc77d49a75954d92f246cc7095e72e36b85d6a07dbdeb9cf46.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
<cache-path name="shared_images" path="/data/data/com.myapp/cache/image_manager_disk_cache/"/>
```

with:

```
<cache-path name="shared_images" />
```

or possibly with:

```
<cache-path name="shared_images" path="image_manager_disk_cache/"/>
```

if you are trying to restrict `FileProvider` to a subset of `getCacheDir()`.